# Download blocked in Firefox, Chrome and Edge. "Couldn't download - network issue"

Tags: windows, security, browser, download, curl

I'm running into a problem on Windows 10 where URLs of a certain type can't be downloaded in Firefox, Chrome or Edge. The URLs look like "http://localhost:8080/6/58/37.pbf".

Using Curl (on Ubuntu through WSL), I can verify that the file downloads just fine, and has the exact content I expect:

```
curl -o test http://localhost:8080/6/58/37.pbf
```

Using any of the three main browsers fails.

Firefox reports (in a popup window):

> C:\Users\steva\AppData\Local\Temp\m_YbgUKn.pbf.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read.

> Try again later, or contact the server administrator.

Chrome (in the status bar):

> Failed - Network error

Edge (in the Downloads list):

> Couldn't download - Network issue

The thing that is really strange is that the browsers *can* access this URI fine, when a website accesses the data through a fetch request (XHR).

I am guessing there is some kind of security setting in play that is preventing me downloading this supposedly "harmful" file. This is a pretty vanilla Windows 10 install. I have not added any third party anti virus software. I have added various extensions to Chrome and Firefox, but not to Edge.

It's also possible there is some kind of issue with gzip encoding on the data source not set up right. When I try to download the file using curl on Powershell (which I'm not very familiar with), I get:

```
curl -UseBasicParsing http://localhost:8080/6/58/37.pbf
curl : The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream.
At line:1 char:1
+ curl -UseBasicParsing http://localhost:8080/6/58/37.pbf
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], InvalidDataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.InvalidDataException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

The headers are as follows (reported in Ubuntu WSL):

```
$ curl -I 'http://localhost:8080/6/58/37.pbf'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
last-modified: Tue, 23 Nov 2021 07:07:24 GMT
etag: 5013110784-1637651244373
content-md5: bgkG68uoqKJm7TRrjnPfzg==
content-type: application/x-protobuf
content-encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 16743
X-Response-Time: 1.063ms
Date: Wed, 24 Nov 2021 05:52:11 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that Chrome and Edge don't allow the download because you are using http. It was announced last year (2020) on this Chromium blog - [Protecting users from insecure downloads in Google Chrome](https://blog.chromium.org/2020/02/protecting-users-from-insecure.html) that:

> Today we’re announcing that Chrome will gradually ensure that secure (HTTPS) pages only download secure files. In a series of steps outlined below, we’ll start blocking "mixed content downloads" (non-HTTPS downloads started on secure pages). This move follows a plan we announced last year to start blocking all insecure subresources on secure pages.
>
> Insecurely-downloaded files are a risk to users' security and privacy. For instance, insecurely-downloaded programs can be swapped out for malware by attackers, and eavesdroppers can read users' insecurely-downloaded bank statements. To address these risks, we plan to eventually remove support for insecure downloads in Chrome.

Try using https.

Comment: Wow, I'm a bit shocked that that applies even to localhost. "Try using https" is not exactly trivial.